# Is it possible to create a pie in pie chart in SPSS or R?

Tags: r, spss, pie-chart

I know it is possible to create such double pie charts in excel like this:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/12/02/group-small-slices-in-pie-charts/

but can SPSS or R do this also?

Comment: You probably could but why would you want to?

Comment: The cited page: "the fact remains that most of us use pie charts sometime or other". If true, this is the problem, not the solution!

Comment: @PeterFlom  I just saw this kind of pie and I wonder if it possible to do so and how, the coding thinking would be interesting.

Answer (score 7):

In relation to R:

The answer to the title question is "yes" ... see `?pie`

As for the second question, the one in the body - it would be possible but would involve some coding. You'd have to draw two pie charts side by side (which could be managed with two calls to `pie`) and use `segments` or `arrows` (and `text` if necessary) to do the additional components of the plot.

Here's a rough example:

[image]

That required the `fig` argument of `par` to get them side-by-side.

(That example required a little fiddling to get right, but it would be possible to write a function to automate the details.)

The main issue I can see would be 'why on earth would you do it?' -- pie charts are a poor way of conveying information of this form. There are alternatives that result in much better ability to distinguish values, and less bias (such as what you get when comparing nearly horizontal vs nearly vertical slices).

Comment: Where's the code for that plot? It would be interesting to see

Comment: @DavidArenburg I figured that since OP asked if it was *possible*, I could safely assume code wasn't required -- simply demonstrated that it could be done (though I've outlined all the calls in my answer - it was just calls to `par(fig=...` to place the components,`pie` to draw them, and `segments` for the grey lines). The endpoints of the grey line segments were a bit of a fudge (since the idea was to show it was possible, I didn't bother writing something clever to do them), but the rest is very standard function calls that are trivially automated.

Comment: This is shooting fish in a barrel, and I can impute @Glen_b's agreement, but the example shows precisely why pie in pie makes a bad idea worse. The problem in the example is that 3 of 8 slices are too thin to show very legibly, which is why their sum becomes its own pie. There would be no such problem with a bar chart or dot chart, in which it is (much) easier to compare all fractions directly.