# How to draw pie of pie or bar of bar charts in R (using ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am trying to create several publication-quality figures with ggplot2.

I have to create a pie of pie, bar of pie, or bar of bar chart. Is there a way to produce such charts with R/ggplot2?

This question is different from this previous question "[Is it possible to create a pie in pie chart in SPSS or R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576906/is-it-possible-to-create-a-pie-in-pie-chart-in-spss-or-r)" in the following respects:

1. I ask if it is possible to produce such a chart using ggplot2 library.
2. The proposed answer does not contain any code example.
3. From an aesthetic perspective, the proposed solution is of subpar quality.

**Examples**

A bar of pie chart:

[image]

A pie of pie chart:

[image]

---

**Example with data**

Here is a table with data and a pie of pie chart of these data made in Excel.

Chart:

[image]

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Class                 | Taxonomic composition (class level) |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Unassigned - other    |                                1.1% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Bacteria - other      |                                0.1% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Coriobacteriia        |                                0.4% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Bacteroidia           |                               35.9% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Deferribacteres       |                                1.3% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Bacilli               |                                4.3% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Clostridia            |                               51.1% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Erysipelotrichi       |                                4.4% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Deltaproteobacteria   |                                0.4% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Epsilonproteobacteria |                                0.5% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| TM7-3                 |                                0.1% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Mollicutes            |                                0.2% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Verrucomicrobiae      |                                0.2% |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to inset a second plot within a pie chart or a bar chart?

Comment: You want pie charts in your pie charts? Can you point us to pictures of examples?

Comment: I added links to the pictures of charts I want to create to my question, sorry for not including them in the first place.

Comment: So you want a pie chart where one (and ONLY one) segment of the pie chart is exploded out into another pie or bar chart? Also, can you edit to give us some simple sample data?

Comment: @Spacedman, I have added a sample of my data to the main post and also added a link to a chart I made in Excel with these data.
I see that my question was marked as a duplicate in the meantime. While I am grateful for the link to an answer, I disagree with that. First, I have asked if it is possible to produce such a chart using `ggplot2` library; second, the proposed answer does not have any code example, so I will have a hard time recreating the plot; and, finally, from an aesthetic perspective, the proposed solution is of subpar quality.

Comment: I agree with @T07072014 that answer is not complete at all in the sense to qualify to mark this question a duplicate. The best solution I found so far is the PierDonut in webr package, since it makes possible to use groups and subgroups as concentric circular sectors.